# Have a promise that polls many times until error is not thrown

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

Let say there's a promise. `checkOnSomeValue()` and for the first two seconds before the process is up the promise `checkOnSomeValue()` is rejected. Then after about two seconds the promise resolves a value.

Is there a way to wrap a promise so that the promise can be run every x milliseconds and then resolve the wrapper promise when the nested promise resolves?

Comment: can you be more explicit with your example ? some sample code would be nice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I would do:

```
function poll(fn, ms) {
    return fn().catch(e => Promise.delay(ms).then(() => poll(fn, ms)));
}
```

Basically, try the function, when it fails wait for `ms` milliseconds and then try again.

```
var polled = poll(checkOnSomeValue, 2000);

polled().then(v => {
  // your resolved value here ^_^
});
```

Or with generators with `const co = Promise.coroutine`:

```
const poll = co(function*(fn, ms) {
    while(true) {
      try {
        return yield fn();
      } catch (e) { 
        yield Promise.delay(ms);
      } // ignore rejections
    }
});
```

Which lets you avoid the recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way.

```
function waiter() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    let interval = setInterval(() => {
      return client.getBalanceAsync('*', 6)
        .then(value => {
          clearInterval(interval)
          return resolve(value)
        })
        .catch((err) => {
        })
    }, 200)
  })
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `setInterval` here, but `setTimeout`, otherwise you might `resolve` the promise multiple times, if `getBalanceAsync` lasts longer then `200ms`.

Comment: `setTimeout` is only gonna call the promise once. I need a way of calling it multiple times.

Comment: This is the deferred anti-pattern, _you_ know better.

Comment: @t.niese resolving the promise multiple times is fine (it works, and will only resolve it once), the problem is that the function itself is called multiple times concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go basically with [Benjamins answer](//stackoverflow.com/a/37022176/5433027), but in a slightly different implementation:

```
function poll(fn, ms) {
    var resolve = () => fn().catch(retry);
    var retry = () => Promise.delay(ms).then(resolve);
    return resolve();
}
```

No big deal. But for some reason this ping-pong-implementation feels better/cleaner/more readable to me. Can't even argument why.